# rectangle select, use fractional in aspect ratio

Tags: gimp

I use the rectangle select to crop an image, but it has to be a fractional number. Let's say 1.6:1

Gimp version is 2.8.16 if I type fractional number GIMP rejecting and back to previous aspect ratio.

Comment: Does that dialog accept the equal ratio `16:10`?

Comment: If you want to crop an image, the Crop tool is better, because it dims the part that will be cropped out so you see better what the result will be. In the standard case it is restricted to the canvas so you see better how you can extract a picture of the given aspect ratio from what you have. And if you tick "allow growing" you can generate a bigger picture that what you start with but still with the required aspect ratio (margins are added).

Comment: Thank you, both of you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More proper tools you should use is the crop tools, as suggested by [xenoid](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/67201/xenoid) on the question comment.

But in GIMP is still possible, with this [trick](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/30216/usr2564301):

> you can multiply your desired aspect ratio with 10.

Let's say you want post-process a picture to [social media](https://later.com/blog/instagram-image-size/) with 1.91:1, you then set like so:

Using crop:

[image: with crop tools]

Using rectangle select:

[image: x base 10]

Alternatively, install [Pix](http://github.com/linuxmint/pix) 2.4.5.

For basic photo editing such as rotate, flip, mirror and resize. But also have enhance focus and adjust contrast.